# Php / Mysql how to insert current user with post

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, insert

I'm rather new to php and mysql, but I've managed to achieve a lot over the past weeks.  I currently have a form that users fill out, and it stores the category and contents they provide.

Additionally, in order to create users I've followed this tutorial ( http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL ) and have working user accounts and security linked with the page.  This may be a simple question but I'm a bit stumped with how to link up a feature I need.

In short I want the insert line from my send_post.php to detect the currently logged in user and store it in a row called "contributor" or the like.

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO mytable (category, contents, date)
VALUES ('$_POST[category]', '$_POST[contents]', NOW())");
```

So it obviously needs to be (category, contents, date, contributor) but I'm not sure how to pull the currently logged in username and define it as 'contributor' in my send_post.php

[Via the tutorial, usernames are stored in a separate table named 'members' along with their numerical ID, email, hashed password, and salt. I know how to call that information but no idea how to get the current user.]

Here is the full send_post.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

//Connecting to sql db.
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","mydbusername","mydbpass","mysqldb");

header("Location: http://mysite.com/1.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Fail"; } else { echo "Success"; }

//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO mytable (category, contents, date)
VALUES ('$_POST[category]', '$_POST[contents]', NOW())");

} else {
   echo 'Access denied. <br/>';
}

?>
```

I would be very grateful and upvote for any help.  Thanks

### Edit, Current send_post.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

//Connecting to sql db.
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mysqldb");

header("Location: http://mysite.com/1.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Fail"; } else { echo "Success"; }

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (category, contents, date, userid) 
                            VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?)');
$stmt -> bind_params('ssi', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt -> execute();


} else {
   echo 'Access denied. <br/>';
}

?>
```

EDIT 2, Errors: (actually I got 3)

[07-Oct-2013 21:05:54] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bind_params() in /home2/mememe/public_html/mysite/send_post.php on line 22

[07-Oct-2013 21:05:54] PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home2/mememe/public_html/mysite/index_3.php:7) in /home2/mememe/public_html/mysite/functions.php on line 12

[07-Oct-2013 21:05:54] PHP Warning:  session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in /home2/mememe/public_html/mysite/functions.php on line 13

Edit 3:  echo returns

Array ( [user_id] => 3 [username] => THEUSERNAME [login_string] => tons of hash infor like 4eb86947c8007ef1d0bb658168a76affa5c666518d3b58d76bf3040dc36d7a399c6c110a8c7f0d9f03d2b4d63271bd1335c61311edb152670f010f04583e7578 )

Comment: Firstable you are wide open for SQL Injections. Second: I didn't hear about sec_session_start() function. What it does? Third: header("Location: http://mysite.com/1.php"); redirects you to another page, so the code below doesn't run never.

Comment: For one thing, you need to replace `sec_session_start();` with `session_start();` - I for one, have never heard of `sec_session_start();` and "IT" needs to be inside ALL your files, included files as well.

Comment: I haven't learned to santise yet, I'm going after that as soon as I understand some of these core concepts.  The sec_session_start is a custom secure way to start the php session located in the tutorial I linked. The header links to the same page that the form is on. When the user submits the category and contents the page refreshes and it shows up on a table on the same page right after they submit it. It..works fine?   

Still need help with the issue I asked about

Comment: And what to do about `header("Location: http://mysite.com/1.php");`

Comment: Again, "sec_session_start"  is just a custom secure session function created in a big functions.php from the tutorial I posted.

Comment: If I have the header redirect in the wrong place, please correct me, but I know it doesn't fail to populate the data or fail to redirect to the same page (which I want) when finished.  What is wrong with it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following that tutorial your current user id is stored in

```
$_SESSION['user_id']
```

The tutorial's login functions are [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL#Create_PHP_Functions)

You need to add a userid field in you MySQL table called "mytable"

then execute an SQL statement like this.

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (category, contents, date, userid) 
                            VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?)');
$stmt -> bind_param('ssi', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
$stmt -> execute();
```

**EDIT**

After reading the tutorial more they cleared the `$_SESSION['user_id']` when executing `login_check($mysqli)` so before you call that insert

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Your code should be like this

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

//Connecting to sql db.
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","mydbusername","mydbpass","mysqldb");

header("Location: http://mysite.com/1.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Fail"; } else { echo "Success"; }

//Sending form data to sql db.
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (category, contents, date, userid) 
                            VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?)');
$stmt -> bind_param('ssi', $_POST['category'], $_POST['contents'], $userId);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> close();

} else {
   echo 'Access denied. <br/>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am testing this out now!

Comment: That seems to break the system the way I have implemented it. Was I wrong to entirely replace my insert statement with your code?  Now it just refreshes and nothing is placed into the table.

Comment: Make sure to add a new field in MySQL.

You have to add `userid` to your table in the database

Comment: I have, I'm trying to paste my current code but the comment section doesn't allow that many characters.  (A bit new to stack overflow)

Comment: Edit added, the new userid field is in mysql also /  Just reading your edit now (I very much appreciate the help btw)

Comment: Negative again I'm afraid, with that exact code posted in (with my tables and passetc filled in obviously) It now posts nothing to the table again.

Comment: echo the $userId variable and see if it shows the userid. Also, you can check the $_SESSION variable and see what's in it by useing `print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: I got 2 errors in the error log upon trying to submit a post, I am editing my main post with them now. / Errors included at the end of original post

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's supposed to be bind_param() my bad.

Comment: OK! Awesome, that has fixed the table and it's now at least inserting the number of the user! I'm going for the user's actual login name associated with that number but what a huge step.  Thank you!

Comment: You should store integer values instead of string when possible you should modify you SELECT statement in order to replace the userid with the user's name

Comment: Righto.  I thank you greatly for your help, I think I've got enough to experiment to get the username called back.  Is there a way I can contact you in the future like private messages or is it better practice to post a new question?